# SSIS job failing because of tilde(~) in the customer last name

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have SSIS job that fails because the customer name  **Cedeñor**  has tilde(~) in it. The error is below. When I look up this customer, I found that the customer's last name has a tilde (`~`) in it. I updated the customer last name without the Tilde and then the job ran successfully.

My question is that how can I change my stored procedure so that it takes away the tilde (`~`) from customer name so the SSIS job doesn't fail in future.

Message

> Executed as user: NSI\EAPSQLAGENT_SUBPROD. returned from
>   PopulateEmailSendQueue 0returned from GetSendEmailRequests 384232390
>   1033937DECLARE @ApplicationID INT, @ErrCode INT, @ErrDesc
>   VARCHAR(8000);  EXEC dbo.usp_GetCustomerApprovalEmail @ApplicationID =
>   1033937, @ErrCode=@ErrCode OUTPUT, @ErrDesc=@ErrDesc OUTPUT result is
>   1Error: The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server
>   Error.  Process Exit Code 1.  The step failed.

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[usp_GetCustomerApprovalEmail]
(
@ApplicationID INT
, @ErrCode INT OUTPUT
, @ErrDesc VARCHAR(8000) OUTPUT
)
AS
BEGIN

BEGIN TRY
    DECLARE @LanguageID INT
    DECLARE @EmailBody VARCHAR(2000)
    DECLARE @FirstName VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @LastName VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @PhoneNumber VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @BarCode VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @MailingAddress VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @MailingAddressAptNo VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @MailingAddressCity VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @MailingAddressState VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @MailingAddressZip VARCHAR(50)
    DECLARE @FromAddress VARCHAR(200)
    DECLARE @Subject VARCHAR(100)
    DECLARE @CustomerEmail VARCHAR(100)

    -- Prep the Email for this customer
    SELECT @LanguageID = C.LanguageID
        , @FirstName = UPPER(C.FirstName)
        , @LastName = UPPER(C.LastName)
        , @PhoneNumber = CASE 
                            WHEN C.MobilePhoneNumber IS NOT NULL THEN C.MobilePhoneNumber
                            WHEN C.LandlinePhoneNumber IS NOT NULL THEN C.LandlinePhoneNumber 
                            ELSE ''
                         END
        , @BarCode = A.BarCodeID
        , @MailingAddress = UPPER(C.MailingAddress)
        , @MailingAddressAptNo = UPPER(ISNULL(C.MailingAddressAptNo, ''))
        , @MailingAddressCity = UPPER(C.MailingAddressCity)
        , @MailingAddressState = UPPER(C.MailingAddressState)
        , @MailingAddressZip = C.MailingAddressZip
        , @CustomerEmail = C.EmailAddress
    FROM Customers C (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN Applications A (NOLOCK) ON A.CustomerID = C.CustomerID
    WHERE A.ApplicationID = @ApplicationID

    -- Get the approval email template for the appropriate language
    SELECT @EmailBody = EmailText
        , @FromAddress = FromEmailAddress
        , @Subject = [Subject]
    FROM EmailTemplate (NOLOCK)
    WHERE EmailTemplateID = CASE
                                WHEN @LanguageID = 1 THEN 3 -- English Approval letter
                                WHEN @LanguageID = 2 THEN 4 -- English Approval letter
                                ELSE NULL
                            END

    -- Replace placeholders with data values
    SET @EmailBody = REPLACE(@EmailBody, '~PhoneNumber~', @PhoneNumber)
    SET @EmailBody = REPLACE(@EmailBody, '~ApplicationID~', @BarCode)
    SET @EmailBody = REPLACE(@EmailBody, '~FirstName~', @FirstName)
    SET @EmailBody = REPLACE(@EmailBody, '~LastName~', @LastName)
    SET @EmailBody = REPLACE(@EmailBody, '~MailingAddress1~', @MailingAddress)
    SET @EmailBody = REPLACE(@EmailBody, '~MailingApt~', @MailingAddressAptNo)
    SET @EmailBody = REPLACE(@EmailBody, '~MailingCity~', @MailingAddressCity)
    SET @EmailBody = REPLACE(@EmailBody, '~MailingState~', @MailingAddressState)
    SET @EmailBody = REPLACE(@EmailBody, '~MailingZip~', @MailingAddressZip)
    SET @EmailBody = REPLACE(@EmailBody, '~CurrentYear~', CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)))

    -- Set date to the proper date
    IF (@LanguageID = 1)
        SET @EmailBody = REPLACE(@EmailBody, '~DATE~', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 101))
    ELSE
        SET @EmailBody = REPLACE(@EmailBody, '~DATE~', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 103))

    -- Return the data needed to send the email.
    SELECT @EmailBody AS EmailBody
        , @Subject AS EmailSubject
        , @FromAddress AS EmailFromAddress
        , @CustomerEmail AS CustomerEmailAddress

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    Declare @ErrorNumber int,
            @ErrorSeverity int,             
            @ErrorState int,            
            @ErrorProcedure varchar(8000),
            @ErrorLine int,                     
            @ErrorMessage varchar(8000)

    Select
        @ErrorNumber = Error_Number(),
        @ErrorSeverity = Error_Severity(),
        @ErrorState = Error_State(),
        @ErrorProcedure = Error_Procedure(),
        @ErrorLine = Error_Line(),
        @ErrorMessage = Error_Message()

        Set @ErrCode = @ErrorNumber  
        Set @ErrDesc = 'Error in usp_GetCustomerApprovalEmail:  ' + @ErrorMessage  

    Execute dbo.[usp_EmailErrorGenerate_Gen]
        @ErrorNumber,
        @ErrorSeverity,
        @ErrorState,
        @ErrorProcedure,
        @ErrorLine,
        @ErrorMessage
END CATCH
END
```

Comment: What's the column type for LastName?

Comment: The column is Varchar(50), null

Comment: Are you able to run the package in BIDS/VS using this data? Maybe there is a better error message.

Comment: I will have to wait until this happens again as their are no more customer's that have tilde in there name. I wanted to be proactive and see if I can fix  the issue before it occurs again.

Comment: Why do you have to wait. Create some test data. You need data type nvarchar

Comment: IF you're sure, then use `REPLACE`. eg: `REPLACE(@LastName , '~', '')`

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I am pretty sure: if you change the column from varchar to nvarchar it will work...

Answer (score 0):

Add this after '--Return the data needed to send the email':

```
SET @EmailBody = Replace( @EmailBody COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI, 'a', 'a' );
SET @EmailBody = Replace( @EmailBody COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI, 'e', 'e' );
SET @EmailBody = Replace( @EmailBody COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI, 'i', 'i' );
SET @EmailBody = Replace( @EmailBody COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI, 'o', 'o' );
SET @EmailBody = Replace( @EmailBody COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI, 'u', 'u' );
SET @EmailBody = Replace( @EmailBody COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI, 'y', 'y' );
SET @EmailBody = Replace( @EmailBody COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI, 'n', 'n' );
SET @EmailBody = Replace( @EmailBody COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI, 'œ', 'oe' );
SET @EmailBody = Replace( @EmailBody COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI, 'æ', 'ae' );
SET @EmailBody = Replace( @EmailBody COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI, 'ß', 'ss' );
SET @EmailBody = Replace( @EmailBody COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI, 's', 's' );
SET @EmailBody = Replace( @EmailBody COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI, 'A', 'A' );
SET @EmailBody = Replace( @EmailBody COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI, 'E', 'E' );
SET @EmailBody = Replace( @EmailBody COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI, 'I', 'I' );
SET @EmailBody = Replace( @EmailBody COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI, 'O', 'O' );
SET @EmailBody = Replace( @EmailBody COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI, 'U', 'U' );
SET @EmailBody = Replace( @EmailBody COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI, 'Y', 'Y' );
SET @EmailBody = Replace( @EmailBody COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI, 'N', 'N' );
SET @EmailBody = Replace( @EmailBody COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI, 'Œ', 'OE' );
SET @EmailBody = Replace( @EmailBody COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI, 'Æ', 'AE' );
SET @EmailBody = Replace( @EmailBody COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI, 'ß', 'SS' );
SET @EmailBody = Replace( @EmailBody COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI, 'S', 'S' );
```